# K shortest path python

Tags: python, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm having issues in finding K shortest path from a source called S to a destination called T. My Code looks like this

```
K = 4
S = 'C'
T = 'A'
B = {}
P = set()
count = {}
for U in graph.keys():
    count[U] = 0 

B[S] = 0 
while(len(B)>=1 and count[T]<K):
    PU = min(B, key = B.get)
    cost = B[PU]
    U = PU[len(PU)-1]
    del B[PU]
    count[U] += 1 
    if U==T:
       P.add(U)
       if count[U]<=K:
          V = graph[U].keys()
          for v in V:
             if v not in PU:
                PV = PU+v
                B[PV] = cost+1
```

This is equivalent to the actual code equivalent of Pseudo Code which can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing . The actual variables are also the same as in Pseudo Code.Furthermore, my graph looks like this:

{

```
'A': {'C': 4.0, 'B': 10.0, 'E': 10.0, 'D': 10.0, 'G': 1.0, 'F': 2.0, 'I': 3.0, 'H': 3.0, 'J': 10.0}, 'C': {'A': 4.0, 'B': 5.0, 'E': 9.0, 'D': 6.0, 'G': 9.0, 'F': 10.0, 'I': 5.0, 'H': 10.0, 'J': 5.0}, 'B': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 10.0, 'E': 8.0, 'D': 1.0, 'G': 8.0, 'F': 4.0, 'I': 2.0, 'H': 2.0, 'J': 6.0}, 'E': {'A': 9.0, 'C': 5.0, 'B': 10.0, 'D': 4.0, 'G': 9.0, 'F': 9.0, 'I': 3.0, 'H': 3.0, 'J': 7.0}, 'D': {'A': 4.0, 'C': 6.0, 'B': 5.0, 'E': 7.0, 'G': 1.0, 'F': 1.0, 'I': 2.0, 'H': 9.0, 'J': 3.0}, 
'G': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 10.0, 'B': 3.0, 'E': 1.0, 'D': 10.0, 'F': 5.0, 'I': 5.0, 'H': 6.0, 'J': 1.0}, 'F': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 3.0, 'B': 6.0, 'E': 7.0, 'D': 8.0, 'G': 10.0, 'I': 1.0, 'H': 8.0, 'J': 2.0}, 'I': {'A': 1.0, 'C': 1.0, 'B': 2.0, 'E': 1.0, 'D': 6.0, 'G': 7.0, 'F': 1.0, 'H': 6.0, 'J': 2.0}, 
'H': {'A': 3.0, 'C': 4.0, 'B': 5.0, 'E': 1.0, 'D': 2.0, 'G': 6.0, 'F': 4.0, 'I': 1.0, 'J': 4.0}, 
'J': {'A': 5.0, 'C': 6.0, 'B': 1.0, 'E': 8.0, 'D': 7.0, 'G': 9.0, 'F': 8.0, 'I': 10.0, 'H': 1.0}}
```

My Output looks like this

```
{'A'}
```

Whereas there should be four paths.

Also, Please Note I'm not allowed to Use Networkx or Graph libraries. I have to use the basic libraries in Python only.

Is Someone able to understand the Problem ?

Comment: What do you want your output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes in your code. There was an error in your where you check if the node is the target and the code following that.

```
K = 4
S = 'C'
T = 'F'
B = {}
P = set()
count = {}
for U in graph.keys():
    count[U] = 0

B[S] = 0
while(len(B)>=1 and count[T]<K):
    PU = min(B, key = B.get)
    print('Minimum Distance found in this loop : ' , PU)
    cost = B[PU]
    U = PU[len(PU)-1]
    del B[PU]
    count[U] += 1
    if(U == T):
        P.add(PU)
        print('Closest neighbour of ' , S , ' is : ', U)
        print('Reached target')
        print('Final map : ', P)
        exit(0)
    else:
       if count[U] <= K:
          V = graph[U].keys()
          print('Looking at neighbours of : ', PU)
          for v in V:
             if v not in PU:
                PV = PU + v
                print(PV)
                B[PV] = cost+1
          print('B dictionary is : ', B)
```

Run this program and you will get something like :

```
Minimum Distance found in this loop :  C
Looking at neighbours of :  C
CA
CB
CE
CD
CG
CF
CI
CH
CJ
B dictionary is :  {'CA': 1, 'CB': 1, 'CE': 1, 'CD': 1, 'CG': 1, 'CF': 1, 'CI': 1, 'CH': 1, 'CJ': 1}
Minimum Distance found in this loop :  CA
Closest neighbour of  C  is :  A
Reached target
Final map :  {'CA'}
```

The output should be fairly self-descriptive. 
Also, you have weights associated with each node (I presume it is that), then I don't understand why you increment the distance count by just 1 to each corresponding neighbour

Comment: It works for S and T < 10, Could U explain what could be wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean? For what source and target does it not work?

Comment: I increment it by 1 as I have Unit Weights between all the edges, though I forgot to mention it earlier...

Comment: What do you mean by **It works for S and T < 10** ? Can you please explain?

Comment: Thank You.... Well, as an example , Let's Say If I have a graph with let's say 100 Nodes, and So If I give the algorithm S>10, and T>10, it does not return anything...

Comment: It only works if the Given Starting Node and Ending Node are digits between 0-9, My guess is the issue is on this line U = PU[len(PU)-1]

Comment: Your `nodes` are **A - I** in this case. I don't know why you are giving it a numerical value greater than 10. Well, if you have changed your graph, please post it with the question to get any help.

Comment: Could you see this Question which I Posted (in Detail) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100791/k-shortest-path-python-not-working?noredirect=1#comment75221914_44100791...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:
Bring the `if count[U]<=K:` out under while loop, not if.

Problem 2:
change this:

```
if U==T:
   P.add(U)
```

to this:

```
if U==T:
   P.add(PU)
```

Problem 3: I am a bit confused about this. 
change `PU = min(B, key = B.get)` to this `PU = min(B,key=lambda x:B[x])`

It worked for me, so let me know if you run into additional problems.